# nginx only sometimes passes query params in rewrites?

Tags: nginx

I'm confused about some nginx behavior.

I have two web servers, one running on `app.abc.com`, and another running on a random Cloud Run domain (looks like `xyz-as.a.run.app`). Both of them use the same API, running on `api.abc.com`. They rewrite requests to the API - example, `app.abc.com/api/object` hits `api.abc.com/object`.

The two servers have identical nginx configs, including the following block:

```
resolver 8.8.8.8;
set $apihost api.example.com;
location ~ ^/api/(?<route>.*) {
  proxy_ssl_server_name on;
  proxy_pass $apihost/$route;
}
```

On `app.abc.com`, this works perfectly. However, on `xyz-as.a.run.app`, the rewriting works for the "base" route, but drops all query params. So:

```
app.abc.com/api/object?q=val      -->   api.abc.com/object?q=val 
xyz-as.a.run.app/api/object?q=val -->   api.abc.com/object
```

Changing the `proxy_pass` in the `xyz` nginx config to:`proxy_pass $apihost/$route$is_args$args` makes this work, but why is the behavior different?

Comment: `app.abc.com` is the strange one because `$route` does not include the query params, because `location` sees a normalised URI where the query string has already been removed.